# JUnit/Mockito Test case gets passed in Debug Mode but not in Run mode

Tags: java, junit, mockito, powermockito

**I am using following method to test the Profile Object updation in my project.**

```java
import org.apache.commons.collections.MapUtils;
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.mockito.invocation.InvocationOnMock;
import org.mockito.runners.MockitoJUnitRunner;
import org.mockito.stubbing.Answer;
import org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest;

import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;


@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({TxUtils.class})
public class MonitoringProfileServicesImplTest extends MonitoringProfileServicesImpl {

    private MutableDataObject mutableDataObject = Mockito.mock(MutableDataObject.class);

    @Mock
    private PersistenceContext<MutableDataObject> persistenceContext;

    @Mock
    PersistenceContextHelper persistenceContextHelper;

    @Mock
    MonitoringDao monitoringDao;

    @InjectMocks
    private MonitoringProfileServicesImpl service;

    private BigInteger profileId;

    private Map<String, BigInteger> attributeNameIdMap;

    private Map<BigInteger, String> invAttributeNameIdMap;

    ResponseBean responseBean = new ResponseBean();


    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        Mockito.when(persistenceContextHelper.getLocalPersistenceContext()).thenReturn(persistenceContext);

        profileId = BigInteger.valueOf(Long.valueOf(1L));

        attributeNameIdMap = new HashMap<String, BigInteger>();
        invAttributeNameIdMap = new HashMap<BigInteger, String>();
        attributeNameIdMap.put("key", BigInteger.valueOf(1111L));
        invAttributeNameIdMap = MapUtils.invertMap(attributeNameIdMap);
    }


 @Test

public void testXXXX() {
        MonitoringProfile monitoringProfile =  getDummyMonitoringProfileToBeCreated();

    TransactionServicePALImpl transactionImpl = Mockito.mock(TransactionServicePALImpl.class);
    Mockito.when(transactionImpl.getTM()).thenReturn(new TransactionManagerImplTest());


    Mockito.when(mutableDataObject.getId()).thenReturn(BigInteger.valueOf(1000));
    Mockito.when(mutableDataObject.getName()).thenReturn("Name");

    Mockito.when(persistenceContext.getObjectById(Mockito.any(BigInteger.class))).thenReturn(mutableDataObject);
    Mockito.when(monitoringDao.getAttributeIdsForObjectType(Mockito.any(BigInteger.class))).thenReturn(invAttributeNameIdMap);

    TxUtils mock = PowerMockito.mock(TxUtils.class);
    System.out.println("newresponseBean:::");



        PowerMockito.when(mock.doTxRequired(new Callable<Object>() {
            @Override
            public Object call() throws Exception {

                return this;
            }

        })).thenAnswer(new Answer<ResponseBean>() {
            @Override
            public ResponseBean answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {

                responseBean.setResultObj(monitoringProfile);
                return responseBean;
            }
        });


    ResponseBean newresponseBean = service.updateMonitoringProfile(monitoringProfile, BigInteger.valueOf(1000));
    Assert.assertNotNull(newresponseBean);
    Assert.assertNotNull(newresponseBean.getResultObj());
    Assert.assertNull(newresponseBean.getErrorObj());
}

    }
```

**In run mode it is getting failed on following line

```
PowerMockito.when(mock.doTxRequired(new Callable<Object>().....
```

While in debug mode it is working fine.**

Following is service method code;

```
public ResponseBean updateMonitoringProfile(@RequestBody MonitoringProfile profileToUpdate) {         
        ResponseBean responseBean = TxUtils.doTxRequired(() -> {
            ResponseBean response = new ResponseBean();
            try {
                PersistenceContext<MutableDataObject> localPersistenceContext = persistenceContextHelper.getLocalPersistenceContext();
                MutableDataObject monitoringProfile = localPersistenceContext.getObjectById(profileToUpdate.getId());
                ParamsBuilder paramsBuilder = populateProfileParameterValues(profileToUpdate, monitoringProfile).build();
                localPersistenceContext.flush();
                response.setResultObj(profileToUpdate);
            } catch (NotUpdatedException notUpdatedEx) {
                notUpdatedEx.printStackTrace();
            }
            return response;
        });
        return responseBean;
    }
```

Following exception we are getting while running in Run mode;

```
newresponseBean:::

org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.MissingMethodInvocationException: 
when() requires an argument which has to be 'a method call on a mock'.
For example:
    when(mock.getArticles()).thenReturn(articles);

Also, this error might show up because:
1. you stub either of: final/private/equals()/hashCode() methods.
   Those methods cannot be stubbed/verified.
   Mocking methods declared on non-public parent classes is not supported.
2. inside when() you don't call method on mock but on some other object.


 at org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito.when(PowerMockito.java:495) 
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
 at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
 at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
 at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
 at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
 at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
 at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
 at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
 at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
 at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
 at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
 at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
 at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
 at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
 at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
 at org.mockito.internal.runners.JUnit45AndHigherRunnerImpl.run(JUnit45AndHigherRunnerImpl.java:37)
 at org.mockito.runners.MockitoJUnitRunner.run(MockitoJUnitRunner.java:62)
 at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
 at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
 at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:51)
 at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:237)
 at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
 at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)


Process finished with exit code -1
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take a look at the [help section about asking](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking). When I look at the question I get the impression that is of the type "Why is this not working?". Consider providing a [minimal complete and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), otherwise the question may be closed soon.

Comment: Update details in question.

Comment: Why do you need to preform mock inside of the `synchronized` block? All the mocks must be preformed before an action. No need of synchronized there!

Answer (score 3):

If your observation is really true and you do not run into this problem when stepping through the test case in "debugging" mode; but it is solid when running the test normally, then it must be some sort of timing issue.

I guess the point that you have **synchronized** statement within your test code is an indication that some code you are not showing here will be using multiple threads?!

So given the fact that we will not be able to *repro* this issue; that is the part I would advise you to look into.

Beyond that: you are getting the "mocking specification" part **wrong**. You want to instruct your environment that **when** the static method mock.doTxRequired() is called with *some* argument, then this or that should happen.

In other words: there is no point in providing a **newly** created object in your when() clause. To the contrary: the mocking framework will check at runtime if the argument passed at runtime is **equal** to the object that you specified in your when() clause! And as you are not implementing equals in your anonymous inner class ... PowerMock will **never** determine that the mock was called with that Object.

In other words: you probably want to use either some object that is equal to what will be passed at runtime; or you use an argument matcher like "any()" or so (see [here](http://www.gitshah.com/2010/07/how-to-use-argument-matchers-using.html) for details).

And just for the record: if you have the possibility consider to **not** use static method calls and **avoid** using PowerMock.

Comment: **Thank @GhostCat ! Appreciate your feedback.
Even we tried by removing Synchronized block, it is giving the same problem i.e working in Debug mode and not working in Run mode.

Even we tried with following;**

  `PowerMockito.when(mock.doTxRequired(Mockito.anyObject())).thenAnswer(new Answer<ResponseBean>() {...
<br>  
This is not working and throwing NullPointerException`

Comment: Please update your question accordingly. But then: really look into the [mcve] suggestion. Your code is **way** too complicated to help with. I suggest: you go in, and step by step reduce it. Or the other way round: write a **new** testcase that does **nothing** else but mock that static call. And when that works, you slowly "add" all the things that you have in your current test. That is the only advise I have.

Answer (score 2):

I had same issue. It fails randomly when running tests but always passes when debugging them.

The problem was that my test class was inherited from a base test class and i mocked same service in both of them. after removing the mock in child class, everything fixed

Comment: Had an issue with `@InjectMocks`. It does not injects the objects if they are declared within a parent class.